# Auto format option (=) in Vim doesn't indent HTML+JS correctly?

Tags: html, vim, formatting

Auto formatting (`gg=G`) works perfectly for code like so (example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/auto-format-c-file-in-vim)):

```
fun()
{
for(...)
{
for(...)
{
if(...)
{
}
}
}
}
```

becomes

```
fun()
{
  for(...)
  {
    for(...)
    {
      if(...)
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it fails for more complex code like so (copied from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp))

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

becomes:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Why is the, for example, `<p>` tag not indented in the body? Is this a shortcoming of vim's formatter  or am I using it incorrectly?

**EDIT**: Thank you to everyone who mentioned I should put `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc` file. That made indenting a lot better. However, it is still failing sometimes. observe (copied from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
      <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
      <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
      <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
      <br />
      <video id="video1">
      <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1");

function playPause()
{
  if (myVideo.paused)
    myVideo.play();
  else
    myVideo.pause();
}

function makeBig()
{
  myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight*2);
}

function makeSmall()
{
  myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight/2);
}

function makeNormal()
{
  myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight);
}
</script>

<p>Video courtesy of <a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

doesn't change at all. It doesn't realize that those functions are nested inside the `<script>` tag. Setting the filetype to `js.html` or `html.js` does not help either

Comment: Does it indent as expected for *any* HTML? (e.g. without JavaScript at all)

Comment: This seems to have been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276392/vim-gg-g-aligns-left-does-not-auto-indent

Comment: @Chriseyre2000 I'm testing it out to see if the solution makes it more reliable

Comment: @Chriseyre2000 it did make it more reliable, but continues to fail in certain situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So vim has different formatting/syntax highlighting options for different filetypes.  You can read about it [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Different_settings_for_different_file_types).  So for your regular c++ file the indenting is pretty standard so it normally gets it correct but for your html file you might have different perferences then the pereson who made the format file.  You can edit and look at your formatting configuration in linux under `~/.vim/ftplugin` and the html file will be called `html.vim`.

Also like bill says you may need to turn on the filetype plugin by either setting it in your `~/.vimrc` or enabling it by typing `:filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: If I don't set `:filetype plugin indent on` then formatting doesn't work. If I do set it on, Vim complains that it couldn't call JSLint (Syntastic). How do I reconcile this?