# How to auto indent HTML in ubuntu?

Tags: html, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I just got the HTML files of a website I'm supposed to modify.
The problem is the files are not indented.
I use GEdit and want the HTML code to get auto indented.
I read that Indent Lines Plugin is discontinued in Gedit.

I tried using `gg=G` in Vim. But nothing happened at all.
I also found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277361/1418853) 
that I must change `filetype plugin` on to `filetype plugin indent on`in .vimrc.

But where is .vimrc and how do I edit it? Like a plain text file?
Or how do I indent my HTML then?

**Edit** : I'm a beginner in ubuntu.

Comment: I recommend you to use [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Answer (score 2):

`.vimrc` is in your home directory and you can edit it with any text editor you like 
i.e. type into a shell

```
learner@ubuntu ~> vim .vimrc
```

Comment: I did just that. Changed the directory to home directory 'cd ~' and 'vim .vimrc'. It created a new file with nothing in it.
@pb2q,I did ls -a at home directory and could find no .vimrc. There was a .viminfo though.

Comment: Did you save (`:wq`) your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: It was a brand new file. Ubuntu created it for me. Did I have to save it? If it is  a new file what should I edit in it? The instructions were to replace filetype plugin on to filetype plugin indent on. THere is nothing at all in it.

Comment: if you want to know a bit more about vimrc you can watch steve losh explaining his vimrc at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZuy4gBghho&list=UU5c2IrhA8XUjAXjSWT57jDw&index=8&feature=plcp. - that's where I started. you also might look for `dotfiles` on github.com there you will find for example my vimrc (http://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles - you can download my `vim` folder and rename it to `.vim` and the `vimrc` too, watch out all my plugins are missing though you will find them on github mostly.

Answer (score 1):

`.vimrc` is the vim user configuration file located in your home directory.

Typing:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

will open the file in vim.

Answer (score 1):

To add a tab to the beginning of each line in vim, type the following in command mode (press escape to enter command mode):

```
:%s/^/<TAB>/g
```

You should see the command at the bottom of the screen next to a `:` as you type it. The tab will probably get replaced with `^I` (or something like that.)

- `%` means for every line in the file
- `s` means substitute (as in search/replace)
- the `/` characters separate search and replace patterns
- `^` means the beginning of the line (this is the *pattern* we want to *substitute*)
- `<TAB>` is the pattern we want to use for replacement
- `g` means do it globally (i think)

Here's an example .vimrc file (stuff you can paste into your new file):

```
"  this is a comment 
"
"
"  set autoindent (indent the next line the same
"  as the line before it)
"  
"  this feature will be very helpful if you choose
"  to indent the file manually, which would be a great
"  way to learn vi

set ai


"  set tabstop and shiftwidth to 4
"

set ts=4
set sw=4


"  expand tabs into multiple spaces
"
set expandtab


"  highlight text when you search for it
"  you can search a file in vi by pressing "/"
"  then typing a search term

set hlsearch


"  turn off the annoying feature that causes
"  the screen to bounce all over the place 
"  as you're typing a search term

set noincsearch
```

Comment: Hi jahroy,
I don't know if you understood what I wanted to do. The HTML files I have are currently not indented. I know GEdit allows auto-indenting **while creating new code**,but what I want is to indent the already written code which is not indented. 
Your first suggestion only adds a TAB to each line, and is not of any use to me. I want the code to get that tree structure where the deepest tags have the most TABS before them.

Comment: And what exactly should I type in the brand new .vimrc file to get a **feature** where entering a command in command mode will magically indent my already written unreadable code?

Comment: You could either do some work yourself or use the link provided in the comment under your question.