# Vim re-indentation option

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I want to convert C files from one coding style to other. I can use [indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) and other similar tools. But, I was wondering, if Vim has a built-in support for this kind of need.

Comment: want a coding style different to vim's built-in c style? e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276392/vim-gg-g-aligns-left-does-not-auto-indent

Answer (score 1):

Vim's automatic indenting can be configured in various ways. Your first step is to get it so that it's indenting new code that you type in the style you want.

Then you can reformat any existing code with the `=` command. For example `=G` will reformat from the current line to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no `:KRToAllman` or `:AllmanToKR` command built into Vim. You'll need to play with `indent` or some other external program.

While I doubt you can use it to switch from one style to the other, you could probably take a look at `:h 'cinoptions'` and `:h c-indenting`.