# How to tell Vim to auto-indent before saving

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I have recently started using Vim for my graduate level projects. The main problem I face is that sometimes I check in unindented code. I feel if I can somehow create a shortcut of auto-indent+save+close then that should solve my problem.

My .vimrc file:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set pastetoggle=<F2>
syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
```

Is there any way to create such command shortcuts & override with `:x` (save+exit).

Please let me know.

Comment: Instead of a trigger before saving, use `set autoindent` and indent your code properly in the first place!

Answer (score 19):

Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Restore cursor position, window position, and last search after running a
" command.
function! Preserve(command)
  " Save the last search.
  let search = @/

  " Save the current cursor position.
  let cursor_position = getpos('.')

  " Save the current window position.
  normal! H
  let window_position = getpos('.')
  call setpos('.', cursor_position)

  " Execute the command.
  execute a:command

  " Restore the last search.
  let @/ = search

  " Restore the previous window position.
  call setpos('.', window_position)
  normal! zt

  " Restore the previous cursor position.
  call setpos('.', cursor_position)
endfunction

" Re-indent the whole buffer.
function! Indent()
  call Preserve('normal gg=G')
endfunction
```

If you want all file types to be auto-indented on save, **which I strongly recommend against**, add this hook to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Indent on save hook
autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call Indent()
```

If you want only certain file types to be auto-indented on save, **which I recommend**, then follow the instructions. Lets say you want C++ files to be auto-indented on save, then create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` and put this hook there:

```
" Indent on save hook
autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call Indent()
```

The same would go for any other file types, i.e. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim` for Java and so on.

Comment: Why do you strongly recommend against auto indenting on save?

Comment: @BallpointBen, I strongly recommend against auto-indenting on save for all file types as this will most likely be not what you'd expect.  Instead, put auto-indenting on save hooks only to the dedicated file types as shown in the answer (e.g. for C++).

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend turning on `autoindent` to avoid this problem in the first place. It is *much* easier to work with properly indented code at every stage of development.

```
set autoindent
```

Read the docs via `:help autoindent`.

However, the <kbd>=</kbd> command will indent lines according to the filetype's rules.  You can create a `BufWritePre` autocmd to perform indentation on the whole file.

I've not tested this, and don't know how well it will actually work:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :normal gg=G
```

Read `:help autocmd` for more information on the topic.  `gg=g` breaks down as:

- `:normal` execute as a normal mode editing command rather than an `:ex` command
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>  move to the top of the file
- <kbd>=</kbd> indent until...
- <kbd>G</kbd> ... the end of the file.

I really don't recommend this strategy though.  Get used to using `set autoindent` instead.  It's probably unwise to define this `autocmd` on all files (as with `*`). It could be done on certain filetypes only:

```
" Only for c++ files, for example
autocmd BufWritePre *.cpp :normal gg=G
```

Comment: Do not use `normal` without bang in scripts, `gg=G` does not necessary break down as you written it here in this case.

Comment: This command is helpful unless you have tendency to save the file after every insertion, because it will bring the cursor back to gg, making it not useable.

Comment: @SimonBudin you could use `magg=G\`a` which will create a mark on the 'a' register, reindent the file, then take you back to mark 'a'

Comment: @TylerFowle, this is the exact behaviour I was wanting. Thank you for that gem.

Answer (score 2):

To indent a file that already exists, you can use the shortcut `gg=G` (not a command; just press `g` twice, then `=`, then `Shift+g`), particularly since you are using the `filetype indent` ... line.

[Vim: gg=G aligns left, does not auto-indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276392/vim-gg-g-aligns-left-does-not-auto-indent)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :normal gg=G``
```

Such will indent whole the file and get back to the recent cursor position.

- did tried to add <C-o> <C-o> which failed, however double tick is a robust solution